# Server crash (Error 500) repeatedly (running nginx + gunicorn on EC2 instance)

Tags: nginx, mysql, python, gunicorn, 500-error

Okay, so I'm really confused about what's happening here. I've had my server up and running for about a month and everything was fine. The server was getting very little traffic (about 50-100 requests per day) so I figured that should be the least of my problems. Then, one day I noticed the server is giving Internal Error 500 output. I just restarted Gunicorn and Nginx and everything was fine. Now, about a week later, same problem. I don't get what's happening.

For some context, I'm running a Python application using Gunicorn with a socket passed to Nginx. As part of my application, I initialized a database connection using pymysql as a global to avoid reopening the database connection for each request (I know this isn't a problem for a few dozen users per day, but I'm trying to make this solution generalize to much higher volume).

This is the output from the last successful gunicorn logged messages as well as the first error message (which then largely repeats for every subsequent request). It seems that what's happening is that the database connection variable is somehow getting deleted but I don't understand why or why this just happens occassionally.

```
[] (sys) Ready to run...
[2020-03-31 19:21:03 +0000] [8162] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-03-31 19:21:03 +0000] [8162] [INFO] Listening at: unix:APP_NAME.sock (8162)
[2020-03-31 19:21:03 +0000] [8162] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-03-31 19:21:03 +0000] [8166] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8166
[2020-03-31 19:21:03 +0000] [8167] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8167
[2020-03-31 19:21:03 +0000] [8169] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8169
[2020-04-12 04:16:06 +0000] [8169] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8169)
Loaded
[2020-04-12 04:16:06 +0000] [8167] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8167)
Loaded
[2020-04-12 04:16:06 +0000] [8166] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8166)
Loaded
[2020-04-12 04:16:06 +0000] [8162] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2020-04-12 04:16:06 +0000] [8162] [INFO] Shutting down: Master    
[] (sys) Starting
[] (sys) Ready to run...
[2020-04-12 04:16:14 +0000] [29732] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-04-12 04:16:14 +0000] [29732] [INFO] Listening at: unix:APP_NAME.sock (29732)
[2020-04-12 04:16:14 +0000] [29732] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-04-12 04:16:14 +0000] [29736] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29736
[2020-04-12 04:16:14 +0000] [29737] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29737
[2020-04-12 04:16:14 +0000] [29738] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29738
[2020-04-19 00:41:18,150] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/APP_NAME.py", line 26, in main_page
    add_record("index")
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/APP_NAME.py", line 48, in add_record
    db.conn.cursor().execute(qstr)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 657, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 707, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
[2020-04-19 00:41:18,882] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/APP_NAME.py", line 26, in main_page
    add_record("index")
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/APP_NAME.py", line 48, in add_record
    db.conn.cursor().execute(qstr)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/ec2-user/APP_NAME/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 750, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
[2020-04-19 04:15:22,832] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
```

And this is the relevant Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime
import os, random
app = Flask(__name__)
db = None

class db_connector():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(<redacted>)

db = db_connector()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index.html')
def main_page():
    add_record("index")
    return render_template("index.html")

def add_record(page_name):
   ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
   dtstr = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   qstr = "<SQL insert string redacted>"
   db.conn.cursor().execute(qstr)
```